# Netbeans Unit Testing

Tags: php, unit-testing, netbeans, phpunit

I am using Netbeans 7.2.1 and am having trouble with the PHP unit testing component.

I have created a .php file called 'Calculator.php'. When I try and create a Unit test for this file, I get the following error:

'"@php_bin@"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Am I correct in saying that the problem is that the path to my PHP.exe is not correct in my environment variables?

Can I please have some help to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

I have changed the System Environment Variable as follows:

Variable name: "@php_bin@" and Variable value: "C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\php.exe"

This however does not fix the problem. Can I please have some help to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are right, the error deals with the path specified in Enviorment variable, You should replace @php_bin@ by the path to the php binary. I guess PEAR or PHPUnit installer was supposed to do that.
check out this [Link](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php?/topic/14995-wamp-netbeans-phpunit-selenium-yii/) and follow instructioins.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you please have a look at my edited question?

Comment: are sure the path is correct, am expecting a path string alike to "usr/lib/php5/bin", not the starting of string end of string, kind of path to a "/bin" directory. If you can, please, check in your installation folder of php for a bin directory and try once more.

Comment: My php installation folder does not have a "/bin" directory.